# C/C++ tool to author or create DTD alongside XML

Tags: xml, dtd

In creating a tool to generate an XML document I'd simultaneously like to create the DTD that will match my document (well, root node really). Does such a tool or class exist?  Where might I find it?

Google seems bent on telling me about DTD/XML parsing and precious little on creting the DTD any way but by hand.

I am using LibXML2 on Linux, if that helps.